# Paypal Rest API Recurring Setup Fee Refund

Tags: rest, paypal

I am using PayPal Rest API for recurring billing.
As described in the API i have created a billing plan with a Setup fee $10 and future price $5 and create and execute a agreement. 
Now my question is, now user want to refund of his setup fee($10) and cancel his billing agreement.
I can cancel his billing agreement because we have his agreement id but how can we refund his setup fee because we don't have the transaction id of this transaction.
Please suggest us.

With Regards,
Alok

Answer (score 0):

After you login www.paypal.com, in transaction history page, you can click " Issue refund" button to refund specific transaction. For this setup fee charge, there is also a record and you can refund it.

Comment: Yes you can do using paypal business account but i want to refund using rest API.